# Hard to understand the performance deference between RAID-4 and RAID-5 when it comes to random writes

Tags: hard-drive, raid, operating-systems

The book "*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*" states that (assuming we have `N` disks and `T` is the throughput of one disk).

- RAID-4 random write performance = `1/2 * T`
- RAID-5 random write performance = `N/4 * T`

How I understand RAID 4 and 5:

For each logical random write you do:

1. Read (in parallel)

   - Read data from the data disk
   - Read data from the parity disk
2. Calculate new parity data value
3. Write (in parallel)

   - Write to the data disk
   - Write to the parity disk

Total of 3 physical disk operations.

Why performance of RAID-4 is `1/2 * T`?

How's RAID-5 performance is different here ?

Comment: Where did you get these formulae from?..

Comment: From the  book operating systems:three easy pieces,  and from udacity lecture

Comment: The book should explain the formula in that case.  It’s unclear what your question is exactly, the formula is the formula.  (N/4)*T doesn’t make sense if N=4 that would imply there isn’t a write penalty with RAID 5 which isn’t the case.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked why is RAID-5 better than RAID-4 when it comes to random writes.

Comment: Those formulas are outdated. In the past (SCSI systems) all disks where on the same parallel bus. For that situation they look more or less right, but even then a good RAID controller had multiple busses. In todays world each disk has a nearly independent data-path (SATA or SAS) to the RAID controller. For RAiD5 your work-sequence doesn't apply either. Data and parity are interleaved at the stripe level over all disks in RAID5. 
And a good controller will cache at stripe-level which (on sequential writes) will greatly reduce the required number of reads/writes to physical disk.

Answer (score 0):

### in RAID-4 :

all parities are in one hard. you cant read/write them in parallel so you need to change them one by one . and for every one of them you need to write to data disk(or read that) first. so for N disk you must do n*2 works. so performance is 1/2*T

### in RAID-5 :

if sectors we need to write spread to all disks (random , not sequential). in every hard we need to read a data (for calculate parity of that stripe), write the new data, read the parity of that hard , write the parity. !note : in each hard disk
in each stripe we read data and parity in parallel(1),calculate new parity, write data and parity in parallel(2) but assume that we can nut do that for all the stripes in parallel ( we can not do that in time n/2*t) because one parity and one data are in one HDD.

---

My English is not good but I hope I could help you.

[image]